# How can event driver nginx process high concurrent requests with only 2 worker processes?

Tags: nginx, software-design

As we know nginx is not threaded,only 2 worker processes by default.

And we also know that `accept()` will block until new requests come:

```
        s = accept(lc->fd, (struct sockaddr *) sa, &socklen);
```

How can it handle more than 2 requests at the same time,basically `2` processes running more than `2` routines cocurrently?

Can someone explain this with some pseudo code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is that it uses non-blocking IO in the second process. For some background on what motivated non-blocking IO servers, I suggest reading [the c10k problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) website. Superb.

Anyway, the second process will register with the kernel its interest in *readable events*, *writable events*, and *error events* with a non-blocking IO interface: `select(2)`, `poll(2)`, `epoll(4)`, or similar. `select(2)` is easiest to talk about, so here we go. First, all sockets are opened with `SOCK_NONBLOCK`, to make sure operations on the socket won't block. Second, there's a control loop that is waiting for activity on the client sockets:

```
fd_set *f
FD_CLR(f)
foreach client socket
    FD_SET(socket, f)

n_ready_to_read = select(max(socketvalue), f, NULL, f, 0)

for (i=0; i<max(socketvalue) && n_ready_to_read; n_ready_to_read--, i++)
    if FD_ISSET(i, f)
        handle_input_from_client(i)
}
```

This is just a sketch of how the process discovers when a client has sent data along and the socket *won't block when reading*. So a `read(2)` call on the socket won't block. Of course, since a single server is writing to many clients simultaneously as well, it needs to keep track of the sockets it is writing to, and send data to them when they are ready to accept `write(2)` calls, and similar for handling errors.

There's a better, fuller, example in `select_tut(2)`.

`select(2)` has largely been replaced in newer systems because there was significant overhead in creating the list of fds to check, the `fd_set` is implemented as a 1024-bit bitfield on Linux, and for ABI reasons can never grow beyond that, and since there's no good way to tell the kernel that you're only interested in a *sparse* subset of that list, it must check from 0- *every time*, even if the array doesn't have many fds set.

So, it's been replaced with mechanisms that allow adding and removing specific file descriptors from a long-lived set, that allow for edge-triggered and level-triggered notification of 'ready', and don't perform silly searches over large fixed-size arrays to find the file descriptors you're interested in.

The [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) library provides a wonderful abstraction layer to this process that automatically selects the *best available interface* on a wide variety of platforms, and allows programmers to focus on the code specific to their server.

Comment: @samold,do you mean for `SOCK_NONBLOCK` sockets,`accept()` will return immediately if there's no new request coming?

Comment: @compile-fan, correct, `If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller until a connection is present.  If the socket is marked nonblocking and no pending connections are present on the queue, accept() fails with the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.`

Comment: @samold, what's the difference between `O_NONBLOCK` and `FIOASYNC`?

Comment: @compile-fan, `FIOASYNC` toggles the `O_ASYNC` flag (which is usually set in `open(2)` or `fcntl(2)`) for a file descriptor, which will ask the kernel to send `SIGIO` or `SIGPOLL` to the process when the file descriptor is ready for IO. It is not used often: (a) it is extremely difficult to properly handle IO in signal handlers; they are best left as tiny as possible (b) because signals interrupt the control flow of the program, they 'cost more' to run than standard system calls, such as `select(2)` or `poll(2)` (c) signals provide less information than other calls: only one fd vs many fds.